# How can I obtain the values of an Entity in Laravel-Backpack?

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-backpack

While I was trying to show pictures I made this pleasant discovery in backpack:

```
$this->crud->addFields([
     [   // Upload
        'name' => 'pictures', //<-- this is an Entity
        'label' => 'Photos',
        'type' => 'upload_multiple',
        'upload' => true,
        'disk' => 'uploads'
     ]
]);
```

This fragment of code gives me this:

[image]

My questions is:

What am I doing wrong?

How can get the value 'file' of this two vectors? I need this for display the images.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add 'photos' to the cast array.

Based on the documentation:

> **Step 3**. Since the filenames are stored in the database as a JSON array, we're going to use attribute casting on your model, so every time we get the filenames array from the database it's converted from a JSON array to a PHP array:

```
protected $casts = [
    'photos' => 'array'
];
```

https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#upload_multiple

Comment: But I am using `upload_multiple` no `image` and the problem is how show the current images.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the answer. Did you add 'photos' in the $casts array?